# Are there any results concerning norm/spectral radius product equalities?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

For square matrices $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$, some norms (I am dealing with the spectral norm) satisfy

$\| \mathbf{AB} \| \leq \|\mathbf{A}\| \|\mathbf{B}\|$.

Can we say anything about the case when

$\| \mathbf{AB} \| = \|\mathbf{A}\| \|\mathbf{B}\|$?

How about for

$\| \mathbf{ABA}^{*} \|$ ?

Comment: Is your question when the inequality becomes an equality?

Comment: Yes, when does the inequality become an equality :)

Comment: One case when its equal is when $B$ is any spectral norm preserving transformation matrix e.g. an unitary matrix. Then multiplying by $B$ doesn't alter the spectral norm of $A$

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful - and I assume the converse is not true?

Comment: Oh, is it equal when $A=B$?

Comment: Yes it is a sufficient condition, but not necessary, so the converse is not true. There may be many other situations when they are equal. If $A$ is symmetric, then they are equal if $A=B$ but I dont think its true for non-symmetric $A.$ Let me try to find a counterexample